# giving margin between two divs?

Tags: css, xhtml

In a page I have to display two div one on top and second under it (just like showing something in a column). Requirment is to have 15px margin between two divs.

I tried to set top margin of second div and found the space between them but than top border of second div was gone. I even tried to set bottom margen of 1st div but again the result was same.

Why border of 2nd div disappears ? Please guide how space between them can be achieved without putting an empty div between them and also border of both should be there.

thanks for your guidance and support.

Comment: `margin-bottom: 15px` and/or `margin-top: 15px` should work fine. If it doesn't something is quirky about your site. Do you have a link or example code?

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake. I put border 0 for top. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use [a reset css](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=reset.css&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=reset.c&pbx=1&fp=e503a4fd986e5054) and try again. May be any content in these divs cause this issue.